# Fix for: /usr/lib/libnssutil3.so: undefined reference to `PL_ClearArenaPool'

Tags: linux, make

Error occurs during attempt to make via:

```
cc -m32 -s -o ford_check_password ford_check_pws.o wsl4_cookie_auth.o fds_auth.o -L. -L/ford/thishost/proj/dmadmin/ford/lib -lcrypto -lldap50 -lssldap50 -lprldap50 -lnss3 -lssl3 -lnspr4 -lvalidate4

Error:  /usr/lib/libnssutil3.so: undefined reference to `PL_ClearArenaPool'
```

Comment: Looks like this is part of the Netscape Portable Runtime package. On my RHEL system it's in the `nspr` package. Not sure why people are marking this off-topic though.

Comment: @JoelDavis People are marking it OT probably because the missing symbol `PL_ClearArenaPool` has nothing to do with Unix.

Comment: @Kaz building software on Unix seems like it has a place in Sys admin discussions. I can see it being close to SO, but I think this is an example of valid overlap between the two sites.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the library where `PL_ClearArenaPool` is located. This could be for example `libplds4`, so you add

```
-lplds4
```

as compiler argument.